# How to make `-n=3` the same as `-n 3` in Perl 6?

Tags: raku

Perl 6 has great builtin command-line parsing via `MAIN`. However, I faced a problem which seems to be trivial, but I cannot figure it out.

A simple `MAIN`:

```
sub MAIN(Int :n(:$num)) {
    say "You passed: " ~ $num;
}
```

Then I can call my script as:

```
$ ./test.p6 -n=1
```

or:

```
$ ./test.p6 --num=1
```

But can't with:

```
$ ./test.p6 -n 1  # or even -n1
```

or:

```
$ ./test.p6 --num 1
```

I went through the [design document for MAIN](https://design.perl6.org/S06.html#Declaring_a_MAIN_subroutine) with no luck. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 9):

**2023 update** This was resolved in 2021. See @librasteve's comment.

*[I've deleted all of the rest of this answer except info that might still be still salient for readers with other issues with command line options.]*

For your convenience, here are the other two extant bug reports I found for MAIN: [Usage does not print required type for positional params in MAIN](https://rt.perl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=125251) and [fail to handle numbers as option name for MAIN](https://rt.perl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=127344).

Maybe use an options module such as [Getopt::Long](https://raku.land/cpan:LEONT/Getopt::Long)?

Comment: this issue was resolved as Closed https://github.com/Raku/old-issue-tracker/issues/3949